# Jssor Slider - responsive slides with fixed size navigation

Tags: jquery, css, jssor

Is it possible to maintain the scaleable nature of the actual slides but fix the size/position of the navigation elements i.e. the left and right arrows, bullet navigator etc?

When the slide container div resizes it resizes everything within it including the navigation elements. When the slider is at a size usable on a mobile device the arrows and bullets/thumbnails etc are too small.

I quickly tried moving the navigation elements out of the slide container div but this caused the whole slider to function incorrectly; gets stuck on the loading screen.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

New option $Scale for bullet navigator, arrow navigator, thumbnail navigator is available now.

Please just set $Scale to false.

See [Jssor Slider Options](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html)

Comment: Thanks jssor, I appreciate you looking into it.